# require("d3") sometimes returns 3 instead of object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, requirejs, c3.js

In our Grails project we use c3.js (which depends on d3.js) to show charts. When deployed on a test server the charts work just fine. If I start the application on my laptop, I don't see any charts at all.

The console of Chrome shows the following message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category10' of undefined
```

After a bit of debugging I discovered the following lines in c3.js:

```
function ChartInternal(api) {
    var $$ = this;
    $$.d3 = window.d3 ? window.d3 : typeof require !== 'undefined' ? require("d3") : undefined;
    $$.api = api;
```

I put a breakpoint here and checked the values of `window.d3`, which was undefined and the value of `require("d3")`, which was the number 3 instead of an object!

I have not much experience with Javascript and require.js, but I am sure that the function `require` should return an object instead of an int.

Chrome shows that both c3.js and d3.js have been loaded.

Why does the same code deployed on a test server work fine and deployed on localhost not? Has anyone any idea on how to further investigate the cause of this problem?

**Update 1**

I discovered that if I start this application from a Windows computer this problem occurs. If I start this application from a Linux computer this problem does not occur. It does not matter on which computer the browser is used. Tested with Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m and Firefox 40.0.3.

**Update 2**

I just figured out that d3.js contains many Greek letters. The file is stored in UTF-8 format (according to IntelliJ). If I open the file in Chrome on my Windows computer, the Greek characters have changed into trash. The weird thing is that the response headers for the request for d3.js show that UTF-8 is used:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/javascript;charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 15 Sep 2015 12:59:39 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Can any tell me why on a Windows computer this does not work properly?

Comment: Are you actually using require.js in the browser? That kind of statement is often used for isomorphic apps that can run either in the browser or on a node.js server. In most cases, `window.d3` would be truthy in the browser, so the `require("d3")` would never need to be executed. If you are using require.js in the browser, you'll likely need to post your optimization configuration  before we can help.

Comment: We use it in the browser. I use Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m. The code is too large to give an example. I hoped someone would have had the same problem or a tip on how to search further. If nobody gives such tips then I will make an effort to make a small application that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the cause of the problem. [This issue at Github](https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline-core/issues/23) points out that files in the assets directory of the Grails project are not UTF-8 encoded. I added the VM option `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the run configuration in IntelliJ and that fixed the problem.